# Express/Angular, not redirecting after Passport authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, meetup

In Express I'm using:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/auth/*', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
app.use(router);

app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/app/dist' });
});
```

And in Angular $routeProvider:

```
when('/auth/:type', {}).
```

When I use social login to Meetup `/auth/meetup` it authenticates but doesn't reroute to `/profile/meetup` as specified in the successRedirect Passport:

```
app.get('/auth/meetup', passport.authenticate('meetup', { scope : 'email' }));

app.get('/auth/meetup/callback',
    passport.authenticate('meetup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile/meetup',
        failureRedirect : '/login'
    }));
```

When I click a button with `href="/auth/meetup"`I get a blank screen with the url in the address bar: `http://localhost:2997/auth/meetup` when I refresh the page, I am automatically routed to `'/profile/meetup'`so the authentication was successful.

Why isn't Node/Express/Angular not redirecting to /profile/meetup after authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want angularjs to handle the route as an HTML5 style single page app route. You want the browser to do a full page load for `/auth/meetup`. So in your HTML `<a>` tag add `target="_self"` which will disable the angular router and allow a traditional hyperlink to work.